# what word or phrase describes one who doesn't know about plants/flowers?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I can't name a plant, e.g. i don't know the.difference between snowdrop and orchid. What word or phrase can describe me? Does phrase like "flower-blind" exist?

Comment: In my family we call it "bio-dodgy"  (a play on "biology" and "dodgy") But I don't think that's widely used!

Comment: Do you think a term exists in English for a person who doesn't know a lot about flowers? Is there such a word in your native language? Or are you actually looking for a *structure* like *[ X + "blind" ]* that could apply to someone lacking in any kind of knowledge?

Comment: @gotube i like the last question

Comment: @Tim Does that mean your answer is yes? If so, that's a different question than the one you've asked.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the phrase "botanically illiterate" to describe a lack of knowledge of plants. You could use "illiteracy" in this way to describe a profound ignorance of almost any area of study (the phrases "mathematically illiterate" or "scientifically illiterate", for example, are not terribly uncommon).

If you're bad at taking care of plants, you could be said to have a "black thumb", in contrast to the more commonly referenced "green thumb".

Answer (score 1):

There are also colorful expressions, like

> I can't tell an orchid from my elbow